# Write a string on IplImage

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Is it possible to write a string on a `IplImage` with Opencv 2.1 in C/C++?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [`cvPutText()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.html#puttext):

```
CvFont font;
double hScale=1.0;
double vScale=1.0;
int    lineWidth=1;
cvInitFont(&font,CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX|CV_FONT_ITALIC, hScale,vScale,0,lineWidth);

cvPutText (img,"My comment",cvPoint(200,400), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));
```

Comment: if i have a variable say "score" which is changing in my programm, can i use cvPutText to display this. to print score to console i would use printf("my score is %d",score). is there a way to display using overlay or does overlay have to be string?

Comment: `cvPutText()` will write over the image, i.e. it will change the image data. So if you need to display text over a static image, I suggest you make a copy of the image and then write the text in this copy, so you always have a clear/original image, untouched. But, if you writing in frames from a webcam, then you don't need to bother making a copy.

Comment: ya i understand that. just wondering if you can use %d in cvPutText to display an integer value. Example CvPutText(" Score: %d", myscore etc

Comment: Nope. You need to insert that number in the string before calling cvPutText. Check `sprintf()`