# opencv displaying variable on video

Tags: c, variables, opencv, overlay

is it possible to overlay %d on the screen using opencv?

> CvPutText()

was tried but that cant be done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's pretend I didn't [explained to you in a comment before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538760/176769).

```
int number  = 5;
char text[255]; 
sprintf(text, "Score %d", (int)number);

CvFont font;
double hScale=1.0;
double vScale=1.0;
int    lineWidth=1;
cvInitFont(&font,CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX|CV_FONT_ITALIC, hScale,vScale,0,lineWidth);

cvPutText (img, text, cvPoint(200,400), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

[cvPutText()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/drawing_functions.html#cv-puttext) draws on an image, but it doesn't do formatting - you need to format the string to be printed using sprintf or similar