# OpenCV, non specific text

Tags: opencv, text, constants

```
int t = 0;
//char u;
// Loop controling vars
char keypress;
bool quit = false;
while (quit == false)
{   pFrame = cvQueryFrame(pCapture);//

   cvLine(pFrame,                        /* the dest image */
       cvPoint(0, 240),             /* start point */
       cvPoint(640, 240),            /* end point */
       cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0),      /* the color; green */
       1, 8, 0);                    /* thickness, line type, shift */



    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    cvCvtColor(pFrame, tempFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    pProcessedFrame = findEdges(pFrame, lowSliderPosition, highSliderPosition, 3);//Επεξεργάσου για να βρεις τις άκρες
    cvSmooth(tempFrame, tempFrame, CV_GAUSSIAN, 11, 11);//Για να αποφευχθούν λάθος εμφανίσεις κύκλου.


    CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(tempFrame, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, tempFrame->height/4, 50, 50, 20, 75);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
 {
     // round the floats to an int
     float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
 cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));

     int radius = cvRound(p[2]);
     cvCircle(pFrame, center, 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );//Ζωγράφισε το κέντρο του κύκλου.
     cvCircle(pFrame, center, radius+1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0 );//Ζωγράφισε το περίγραμμα του κύκλου.
 if (center.y == 240 )
     {cvWaitKey(150);    
 t++;
  }
 else
 {}
 printf("x: %d y: %d r: %d t: %d\n",center.x,center.y, radius,t);
  }

 CvFont font;
     cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 1, CV_AA);
 cvPutText(pProcessedFrame, "blabla", cvPoint(10, 130), &font, cvScalar(255, 255, 255, 0));

    cvShowImage("WebCam", pFrame);//Εμφάνισε τα κανονικά frame στο παράθυρο αυτό
    cvShowImage("Processed WebCam", pProcessedFrame);//Δείξε τα επεξεργασμένα frame στο παράθυρο αυτό.

    keypress = cvWaitKey(20);//Περίμενε 20 msec.
    if (keypress == 27)//Άλλαξε το flag σε quit αν πατηθεί το πλήκτρο escape.
    {
        quit = true;
    }} //Τέλος του while
```

Hello guys, i believe this question isn't that hard but for some reason i cant seem to find any answers on the internet. Maybe i am not doing some good research.

I am having a counter(integer) on my program which is the one named t. It changes from time to time according to some camera interactions i am doing. I just want this to be shown in the video result, the one named pProcessedFrame.

Command cvPutText that i am including here, doesnt work for me because it can only show specific text. I want it to change from time to time like i mentioned before.

Any other command i am not aware of?

@@EDIT@@

Ok guys this was answered below. I am just putting the final while code, and the declarations out of it.Maybe someone someday will need this. Thanks a lot all of you. xD

```
    int t = 0;
char u=0;
// Loop controling vars
char keypress;
bool quit = false;
char msg[4*1024] = { 0 };
int frame_num = 0;

while (quit == false)
{
pFrame = cvQueryFrame(pCapture);
cvLine(pFrame,                        
    cvPoint(0, 240),            
    cvPoint(640, 240),    
    cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
cvCvtColor(pFrame, tempFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
pProcessedFrame = findEdges(pFrame, lowSliderPosition, highSliderPosition, 3);
cvSmooth(tempFrame, tempFrame, CV_GAUSSIAN, 11, 11);


CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(tempFrame, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, tempFrame->height/4, 50, 50, 20, 60);

      for (size_t i = 0; i < circles->total; i++)
      {
          // round the floats to an int
          float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(circles, i);
      cv::Point center(cvRound(p[0]), cvRound(p[1]));

          int radius = cvRound(p[2]);
          cvCircle(pFrame, center, 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
          cvCircle(pFrame, center, radius+1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2, 8, 0 );
      if (center.y == 240 )
          {
      cvWaitKey(200);    
      t++;
          frame_num=t;
      }
       else
      {}
      printf("x: %d y: %d r: %d t: %d\n",center.x,center.y, radius,t);
      }     

      sprintf(msg, "Counter: %d", frame_num);
      cvPutText (pFrame, msg, cvPoint(50,100), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));             
      cvShowImage("WebCam", pFrame);
      cvShowImage("Processed WebCam", pProcessedFrame);

      keypress = cvWaitKey(20);
      if (keypress == 27)
      {
      quit = true;
          }}
```

Comment: Is cvPutText inside a loop or not? You have an `end of while` comment at the end but I don't see any `while` loop.

Comment: Sorry for that, i have edited the 1st post and now it has the whole while thing.

i am not putting the whole code because it has some huge comments in foreign language that probably most of people here won't understand.

Comment: Please indent the code. It's awful to read code without proper formatting.

Comment: Hello karl. I don't understand what is the problem with the code, i am new to this. If you can explain me i can repost everything if needed. Its not a problem xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`cvPutText()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.html#puttext) is [exactly what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9504144/176769).**

My first tip is a little optimization: place the following code before the **while** loop. Since you only need one font type, there's no need to recreate it at every loop iteration.

```
CvFont font;
cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 1, CV_AA);
```

Now back to the stuff you need to understand: the 2nd parameter of `cvPutText()` is of type `const char*`. So all you need to do is pass a variable with a different text on each iteration of the loop.

The example below retrieves frames from a capture interface and writes the frame number at each image displayed on the screen:

```
while (key != 27)
{
    img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if (!img)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "!!! Failed to retrive frame!\n" );
        break;
    }

    // convert int to char*
    char msg[4*1024] = { 0 };
    sprintf(msg, "Frame number: %d", frame_num);

    cvPutText (img, msg, cvPoint(50,200), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));
    frame_num++;

    cvShowImage("result", img);
    key = cvWaitKey(33);
}
```

Comment: Does he need to declare `msg` inside the loop?

Comment: That could be done outside of the loop as well. I did it here for simplicity purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the advices. I am not really sure if i understand the code you gave me but anyway, i am working at the moment, so i am gonna check it in about 10 hours, when i am going back home.

Comment: Ok, this was easier than expected. Thank you very much sir! :D